# Editing Image Tint in Windows RT App

Tags: xamarin.forms, windows-rt

I have created custom renderers for the Xamarin.Forms Image control for both Android and iOS that allow me to specify an image tint at runtime that is applied to the Image.

In Android I adjust the tint using a color filter on the ImageView:

```
var cf = new PorterDuffColorFilter(Element.TintColor.ToAndroid(), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcIn);
Control.SetColorFilter(cf);
```

In iOS I adjust the tint using the UIImageView's TintColor:

```
Control.Image = Control.Image.ImageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate);
Control.TintColor = Element.TintColor.ToUIColor();
```

Does anyone know of a way to apply a tint effect on the Windows RT Image control?